# FullCalendar Events by day

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using jquery Fullcalendar script http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and I'd like to make the whole day's block clickable when there is an event on it instead of rendering the title on corresponding day's block. Is there any way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would that work in the case of multiple events on the same day? Or will this not happen in your usage? I can help if the latter, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an eventRender() callback, where you modify the element's style to be render over the block.

edit:  There's no relationship between the Calendar cell and the event.  Even FC itself just builds an overlay over the cell when you drag an event.  I suggested that you can style your element to cover the cell similar to how FC creates the overlay.  If that's not what you want, you will have to tweak FC's source.

I tried this:

line 2175, add: `t.getBodyCells = function() { return bodyCells };`

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  var cell = view.dateCell(event.start);
  var colCnt = view.getColCnt();
  var bodyCell = view.getBodyCells();
  var cellElement = bodyCell[cell.row*colCnt + cell.col];
  $(cellElement).css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

You can now set a click event handler on the cell, and disable the event rendering.

Comment: Your solution wouldn't make a day clickable, it can be used to render an event over the day. The author asked (and I am also wondering) if it's possible to make a day clickable instead of rendering an event over it.

Comment: That looks promising. Just one last question, how can I get `cell.row` and `cell.col`?

Comment: Use `view.dateCell()`.  Becareful with `bodyCell`, it exists for certain view types only.  Also, if you don't mind having all cells be clickable, even without event, then use `dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {`